# React-router how to redirect to an Express GET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm using both Express and React for my webapp, because we are migrating rendering from Handlebars to React. However we want to maintain the logic in Express and render only in React. The problem is when I want to do a redirect. This is the client.js with the logic:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// In production, we want to hydrate instead of render
// because of the server-rendering
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App {...window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App {...window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
}

// Hot reload is that easy with Parcel
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

and this is a simple path of Express:

```
app.get('/signup', (req,res)=>{
  const initialState = {component:'SignUp'};
  let context = {};

  const markup = ReactDOM.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}  context={context}>
      <App {...initialState} />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  if (context.url) {
    res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: context.url
    });
    res.end();
  }
  else {
    res.send(generateHtml(markup,initialState));
  }
});
```

the problem is: when I try to redirect like this (and change this.state.redirect):

```
render(){
    return this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to="/login" /> :(
    <div className="ro">HI </div> );
}
```

browser go to /login path, but without call the server. It simple shows a blank page.

This is also my App component:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
  }

  render(){
    if(this.props.component === 'Root'){
      return <Root />;
    }
    else if(this.props.component === 'Login'){
      return <Login />;
    }
    else if(this.props.component === 'SignUp'){
      return <SignUp />;
    }
    else{
      return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello word {this.props.component}</h1>
        <Button color="danger">Danger!</Button>
      </div>
     );
    }

  }

}
```

that is a Root component that manage where to go.

How to fix this? I don't want to use react-router to handle the route, we want to maintain all on Express.
Thanks

Comment: You would typically want to stick with either client side routing or server side routing, not both

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings what do you mean?

Comment: `<Redirect to="/login" />` is routing on the client side, so it will not make a request to the backend

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings it's the problem I want to solve, how could do that? I couldn't do a post to express

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I've also followed this guide that could do what I want to do: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When client-side rendering, instead of setting state to render a `<Redirect>`, you can `window.location.replace("/login");`

to simulate a `<Redirect push>`: `window.location.href = "/login";`

On the server-side, you can continue to use the `<Redirect>`

Answer (score 0):

You can host your express app on a subdomain :

```
<Redirect to="http://express.myapp.com/login" />
```